# Preserving authentication cookies, but disallowing concurrent access at different sites

Tags: authentication, web-applications, cookies

I have a web application where I want users to only be able to use it from one location (meaning a user can't actively be using the application at two locations).  Currently I got this working in a very common way by only allowing 1 cookie session to be valid and removing any existing ones when a user logs in.  Unfortunately I've been told that my method of only allowing 1 cookie is unacceptable because my users move around a lot to different sites and are tired of having to login every time.  An easy solution would just be to allow more than 1 cookie, but I can't do this because I need to make sure a user account is not being used at two locations at the same time.

I'm wondering what is the best way to implement a system like this where a user can't be active at more than 1 location, but shouldn't necessarily have to login at every location they visit.

One possible idea I had was to allow multiple cookies to be recorded, but once a cookie becomes active (meaning I notice that session navigating the application) all of the other cookies are locked out for a certain timelimit like 15 mins.  If no cookie session has been active for 15 mins then allow any cookie to login and gain dominance over the others untill it exceeds the timelimit.

Edit: It's ok for them to remain logged in after they leave a location

Comment: Hopefully this isn't too situationally specific, but I think it general enough problem that others could be dealing with this as well.

Comment: I think your solution with 15 mins lock sounds good, except I would recommend to add a button to "leave current location" so that user could move location quickly if necessary not waiting the 15 mins. Is something you don't like about it? So, what's the question?

Comment: The user can only be in one location at a time, so why do you want to enforce this in code as well? Are you afraid your users will share their credentials with others? Are you afraid unauthorised users will use an unguarded workstation that's still got a valid cookie? What are you trying to prevent from happening?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to log their last ip address and at what time that access was. On each access, you can check their last access.

If the last access is from the same ip, let them through.

If the last access is from a different ip, check how long ago that was. You can then define a cut-off  point for how long they need to be idle before they can access it from another location. 15 minutes seems reasonable.

All of this can be done on the backend and this would possibly provide a higher level of security.

Answer (score 1):

The browser allows users to store their credentials. Let them use this feature to log back in without hassle.

Answer (score 0):

No need for a timeout. Allow multiple cookies, but only one active one.

Instruct your users to close the application when they leave their workstations. Make this something that's easy to do. Put a close button on each page or perhaps catch `onBeforeUnload` and notify the server that the page is no longer being displayed. Do keep the session when the user closes the application, but mark it as currently inactive.

When you get a request with a cookie that belongs to an inactive session, activate that session without complaints if the user has no other session active.

If the user still has another session active, something fishy is going on. So remove all sessions and send the user to the login screen.
(That'll teach them :) )

Comment: Software doesn't teach users anything and software that tries to will be hated. Don't punish the user for not logging out if remaining logged in is a business requirement, just go with the timeout.

Comment: @CodeCaster From the sound of things, the business has two conflicting requirements. They want to have their cake and eat it too. Am curious about the why. But you can fill in a less restrictive way to handle this case of course.

Comment: While you do have a point there, I'm sure users won't like it if the system logs out all their sessions if they forget to log out one, especially given OP's comment the users aren't used to logging in again. Whether that is good or not is a different story.